# Having difficulty setting up Gradle multiproject build for existing repository layout

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to craft a Gradle multiproject build for a situation in which my project layout is already dictated to me. I have something like this:

```
-->Shared\
---->SharedComponent1\
------>build.gradle
------>src\
...
---->SharedComponent2\
------>build.gradle
...
-->Product1\
---->ProductComponent1\
------>build.gradle
---->ProductComponent2\
------>build.gradle
...
---->build\
------>settings.gradle
```

My settings.gradle looks like this:

```
rootProject.name = 'Product1'
rootProject.projectDir = new File( "${ProjectsRoot}" )

include 'Shared:SharedComponent1'
include 'Shared:SharedComponent2'
include 'Product1:ProductComponent1'
include 'Product1:ProductComponent2'
```

When I run Gradle in the build folder like this:

```
gradle -PProjectsRoot=c:\my\project\root\dir projects
```

I get:

```
:projects

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'build'
No sub-projects

To see a list of the tasks of a project, run gradle <project-path>:tasks
For example, try running gradle :tasks

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

i.e. it doesn't find the projects I'm trying to build.
Is what I'm trying to do possible with Gradle's multiproject support? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Here is a working example that works with gradle2.2.1 but not with android studio 1.0.2 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936433/relative-gradle-project-dependency-with-holoeverywhere/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A couple of pointers:

- Gradle strictly separates the *logical* project hierarchy (the way Gradle organizes your build into a logical hierarchy of projects) from the *physical* directory layout. Just about any mapping is possible. (One exception that comes to mind is that you can't have two projects sharing the same project directory.)
- To implement a custom directory layout, you'll have to set `projectDir` for all projects, not just the root project. You should use relative paths, e.g. `rootProject.projectDir = new File(settingsDir, "../foo")` and `project(":sub1").projectDir = new File(rootDir, "bar")`. Here, `settingsDir` refers to the directory containing `settings.gradle`, and `rootDir` is a shorthand for `rootProject.projectDir`.
- To configure projects generically, you can recursively walk `(root)Project.children`. Note that `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle` use different types to represent a project - [ProjectDescriptor](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/ProjectDescriptor.html) and [Project](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html), respectively.
- Gradle has to be invoked from the directory containing `settings.gradle`, or a subdirectory thereof. From a usability perspective, it is therefore best to put `settings.gradle` into the root of the directory hierarchy.

For more information, see [Settings](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html) in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html), and the [Multi-Project Builds](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#multi_project_builds) chapter in the Gradle User Guide.

Comment: Fantastic, Peter, thanks. That's resolved a whole heap of misconceptions that I had about how this works. I'll post another answer below showing the final example that worked for me in case others are struggling in the same area.

Comment: Glad it helped. Correction: According to the docs, a property set with -P is also available in the settings script. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: One thing that helped me tremendously was to realize that settings.gradle should only live in the root project.

Answer (score 12):

For completeness, the `settings.gradle` that solved my specific example above is as follows:

```
rootProject.name = 'Product1'

def projectTreeRootDir = new File( "${ProjectsRoot}" )

// Shared components

def sharedRootDir = new File( projectTreeRootDir, 'Shared' )

include ':SharedComponent1'
project( ':SharedComponent1' ).projectDir = new File( sharedRootDir, 'SharedComponent1' )

include ':SharedComponent2'
project( ':SharedComponent2' ).projectDir = new File( sharedRootDir, 'SharedComponent2' )

// Product components

includeFlat 'ProductComponent1', 'ProductComponent2'
```

Clearly this doesn't scale to large numbers of subprojects and it could be done significantly better using the hints provided by Peter above.